# opencv doesn't use all GPU memory

Tags: python-3.x, opencv, gpu, cvlib

I'm trying to use the cvlib package which use yolov3 model to recognize objects on images on windows 10.
Let's take an easy example:

```
import cvlib as cv
import time
from cvlib.object_detection import draw_bbox


inittimer=time.time()
bbox, label, conf = cv.detect_common_objects(img,confidence=0.5,model='yolov3-worker',enable_gpu=True)
print('The process tooks %.3f s'%(time.time()-inittimer)

output_image = draw_bbox(img, bbox, label, conf)
```

The results give ~60ms.

cvlib use opencv to compute this cnn part.

If now I try to see how much GPU tensorflow used, using subprocess, It tooks only 824MiB.

while the program runs, if I start nvidia-smi it gives me this result:

[image]

As u can see there is much more memory available here. My question is simple.. why Cvlib (and so tensorflow) doesn't use all of it to improve the time's detection?

EDIT:

As far as I understand, cvlib use tensorflow but it also use opencv detector. I installed opencv using cmake and Cuda 10.2
I don't understand why but in the nvidia-smi it's written CUDA Version : 11.0 which is not. Maybe that's the part of the problem?

Comment: Have you installed OpenCV from source with CUDA support ?

Comment: Yes I did, that's why it use some GPU there and not the CPU.

Comment: You probably tried to install both version at the same time. Then you didnt uninstall the previous one before installing new one. What is the output of ```nvcc --version``` and what is your driver ?

Comment: In "CUDA Version:" nvidia-smi shows you the highest CUDA version the  currently installed Nvidia driver supports. That number will go up or down as you change drivers. nvidia-smi's  CUDA Version  does not reflect you currently installed CUDA version.  You can have multiple CUDA versions installed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it! The problem come from the fact that I created a new `Net` object for each itteration.

Here is the related issue on github where you can follow it: https://github.com/opencv/opencv/issues/16348

With a custom function, it now works at ~60 fps. Be aware that cvlib is, maybe, not done for real time computation.

Answer (score 2):

You can verify if opencv is using CUDA or not. This can be done using the following

```
import cv2
print(cv2.cuda.getCudaEnabledDeviceCount())
```

This should get you the number of CUDA enabled devices in your machine. You should also check the build information by using the following

```
import cv2
print cv2.getBuildInformation()
```

The output for both the above cases can indicate whether your opencv can access GPU or not. In case it doesn't access GPU then you may consider reinstallation.

Comment: thanks a lot for your answer.
As mentionned before, opencv use Cuda and GPU

Trying the first par of your answer I have the result : 1 
which mean that I have one device enable with cuda (RTX 2060)

But what is strange is, it doesn't use it all!

The second part give me the build process, the only missing thing is FAST_MATH that I disabled.

Comment: @Panda50 While executing cmake, did you had the flags WITH_CUDA=ON, ENABLE_FAST_MATH=1 and CUDA_FAST_MATH=1 ?

Comment: Yes, I built it again with FAST_MATH=1 to test and it doesn't change anything.

Comment: @Panda50  can you share your installation script? I would like to recreate the issue you are facing

Comment: @Panda50 Not exactly, what you shared is your output of the installation process. I am looking for some sort of shell script or instruction using which I can install the OpenCV in exact same you installed. Given that I will be able to recreate the problems you are facing.

Comment: I think I understand what you mean, the problem is I'm using it on windows 10 with Cmake. I don't use any script for it.

Comment: and I have to say that it works! It's just a bit long. With a 2060 TI I hit only 31 fps in the best case : using ' net.setPreferableTarget(cv2.dnn.DNN_TARGET_CUDA_FP16)' and decrease the input image scale to 288x288 (related issue https://github.com/opencv/opencv/issues/16348 )

Answer (score 0):

```
workon opencv_cuda                                                                                                          
cd opencv                                                                                                                              
mkdir build                                                                                                                                
cd build                                                                                                                               
cmake -D CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=RELEASE
```

and share the result.
It should be something like this
[image]

Comment: I'm on windows 10 but when I'm typing the code recommended by @ravikt I have:

```
  NVIDIA CUDA:                   YES (ver 10.1, CUFFT CUBLAS FAST_MATH)
    NVIDIA GPU arch:             60 61 70 75
    NVIDIA PTX archs:

  cuDNN:                         YES (ver 7.6.5)
```

Comment: type make -j(n) n is the number of cores your system have. lets say if its 4 then type make -j4

Comment: checkout step 6 of this link and further. https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2020/02/03/how-to-use-opencvs-dnn-module-with-nvidia-gpus-cuda-and-cudnn/

Comment: I think I put what you need in the @ravikt comment session